# F9 - Lift Off from "Landing Legs"

Tags: falcon-9, launchpad

Could it ever be possible for Falcon 9 to lift off from its own "landing legs"? i.e. no strongback, no complex launch pad support, just land somewhere, get a new second stage and a tank of gas and off it goes?

Comment: It looks like your question has been answered before. This happens once in a while, don't fret too much if it is closed quickly, and feel free to ask a new question. *Welcome to Space!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

- The landing legs are made to support a 30-ton empty stage, not a 600-ton full rocket.
- The thermal loads on launch are much higher and would likely lead to damage on the legs.
- The strongback is needed to fill the second stage tanks and to provide connections to the payload.
- The launchpad is carefully designed to lead the flames away from the rocket. Just lifting off from a concrete slab would damage the concrete, and subject the rocket to more vibration (noise reflecting off the concrete)

Comment: Suppose you only wanted to get off the ground (maybe to hop a few km to the launched, so you'd only need a moderate amount of fuel. Would that make a difference?